# Fiverr style textarea with css and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i wan't to make a textarea that looks like fiverr textarea to create a gig, the text "I wil" is fixed and disabled and i can write just next to it.
[image]

i managed to create something similar with css
[image]
but i'm stuck on the following issue when the text is written on many lines the first fixed text isn't moved to top with the other lines that the user wrote 
[image]

i know javascript is the solution but i don't know exactly how , any ideas please ? i'm using angularJS if there is anything specific to angular it's also welcomed. here is my code :

```
 <label class="item item-input" id="questionArea" style="margin-top: -30px;">
        <textarea class="text-combien" style="height:100px;padding-right:15px;" ng-model="question.text" placeholder=""> </textarea>
        <div class="before-text">Pour Combien,</div>
        <div class="ask-text">?</div>
      </label>
```

Comment: you could make the border of the actual input trasparent with a .before with the "i will" part, and wrap it in a div with border

Comment: something like this: http://jsbin.com/tolifa/1/watch?html,css,output ?

Comment: @balexandre thanks for the reply, the jsbin you wrote is what i have now but take a look at the third picture. that's what happens when a user write more than two or three lines

Comment: @zerzer yes, but you can either hide the `.before-title` when there's more lines, or make the `textarea` auto-sizable that would grow automatically upon each new line... plenty of jquery plugins for that :)

Comment: @vsync yes i reposted this question because i didn't get an answer for this one

Comment: @zerzer - that is spamming...you can just edit your question or think of a better title to make it more "attractive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ttwbxwon/66/
with the following javascript function binded to onscroll event of the textarea :

```
function heigthChange() {
  var e = document.getElementById("text-combien"); 
  var height =  e.scrollTop; 
  document.getElementById("before-text").style.top = (0 - height) + "px" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-indent` CSS property on the textarea, and then you just need to position a span to go where you've indented the text. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7ds0n49/). You will need to tweak the positioning/sizing based on what font you want.

```
<div id="container">
<textarea placeholder="do something I'm really good at"></textarea>
<span class="textbox-prefix">I will</span>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.textbox-prefix{
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;
    left:10px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

textarea{
    text-indent: 50px;
    width:300px;
    height;200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: yes this is what i have now but look at the picture 3 that's my real problem , when i write too many lines i need the text to move up